# S3 credentials for a public bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this snippet to upload a file on S3

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('bucketname', timestamped_filename).put(Body=open(FILE_SAVE_PATH, 'rb'))
```

my bucket has a delete/upload permission for everyone, so it does work on my Windows machine.
However, when I try to run the same code on my Mac it throws

`botocore.exeptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`

Is this behavior normal?
And what kind of credentials I can possibly provide if I'm accessing a public bucket?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making an API call to AWS, **valid credentials must be provided**. These credentials are associated with an IAM User and grant access to AWS services.

When making API calls (or using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)) **from an Amazon EC2 instance**, these credentials can be granted to the EC2 instance by assigning an IAM Role to the instance at launch time.

When making calls **from a non-EC2 computer**, credentials must be provided via a configuration file or environment variables.

It appears that your Windows machine is either an EC2 instance with a role, or it has a local configuration file with valid credentials; and it appears that your Mac has neither of these.

See: [boto3 Credentials documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html)